# Trying to load a .properties file into Resource bundle getting error "Can't find bundle for base name"

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to load a `.properties` file into my `ResourceBundle`

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/sample/resources/language_en.properties");

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/layout/test_form.fxml"), bundle);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name /sample/resources/language_en.properties, locale en_US
```

[image]

Can't figure out why. I've checked the path multiple times `/sample/resources/language_en.properties` for spelling mistakes. I've also tried rebuilding the project (Using IntelliJ).

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Use `ResourceBundle.getBundle("/sample/resources/language_en");`

Comment: That also throws the same error ```Can't find bundle for base name /sample/resources/language_en```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading resource bundle don't have `.properties` in basename extensions. Also, remove the leading `/` for the basename.

Use `ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sample/resources/language_en");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I spent an hour on this!

Comment: the leading slash doesn't make a difference - the important part is that is must be _a fully qualified class name_ (see the java doc).

Answer (score 2):

The method `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` takes the base name of the resource bundle, a fully qualified class name (as specified by the class documentation). You can load your bundle like this:

```java
// this will load the base bundle: sample/resources/language.properties
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sample.resources.language");
```

To use the English `ResourceBundle`, you can specify a `Locale`:

```java
// this will load sample/resources/language_en.properties
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sample.resources.language", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Please refer to this tutorial for more information: [Customizing Resource Bundle Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/control.html)